# VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled. issue

Tags: android, android-multidex

I already have tried all the solutions that are in internet but any of them works, this is my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rocketjourney"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 68
    versionName "4.41"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.rocketjourney.helpers.CustomTestRunner"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    jumboMode = true
}`

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    flatDir { dirs '../aars' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
    etc...
}`
```

my manifest looks like this:

```
<application
    android:name="com.rocketjourney.RJApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

In my `RJApplication.class` I have this code:

```
public class RJApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
  }
```

But my error now is this:

> 11-08 11:54:36.494 5743-5743/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.rocketjourney, PID: 5743
>                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/fabric/sdk/android/services/common/FirebaseInfo;
>                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:22)
>                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
>                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.FirebaseInfo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rocketjourney-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rocketjourney-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:22) 
>                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696) 
>                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.FirebaseInfo
>                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                               ... 16 more
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Hope you guys can help me, I will appreciate it so much!

Comment: What gradle Error do you receive?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add multidex support if your `minSdkVersion` is 21.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l):

> **Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**
>
> Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading multiple DEX files from APK files. ART performs pre-compilation at app install time which scans for classesN.dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for execution by the Android device. Therefore, if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher, you do not need the multidex support library.

So, you need to remove `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` from your build.gradle. Then you need to extend your RJApplication with `Application`. Also remove `MultiDex.install(this);` from your `attachBaseContext()`.

all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true by adding `multiDexEnabled true`. Please refer to [Configure your app for multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Comment: how i have this:
```Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: field ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536```

Comment: Oops... Sorry, you only need to add the `multiDexEnabled true` in your build.gradle. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That's probably another issue. Try changing the crashlytic to this `compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}`

Comment: I already tried adding that line of code but still the same error